# Running into "Timed out" error using for-loop

Tags: python, for-loop

I recently started learning python and came across a site called CodingBat. In one of their exercises (http://codingbat.com/prob/p190859) I am supposed to make a function that takes three inputs: "small", "big" and "goal" and returns a single value as an output. The output should be the number of "smalls" needed to get to "goal" after using a sufficient amount of "bigs" where the value of one "small" = 1 and the value of one "big" = 5. When using the following code the site gives me an error "Timed out".

```
def make_chocolate(small, big, goal):

  for i in range(small+1):
    for j in range(big+1):
      if 5 * j + 1 * i == goal:
        return i
  return -1
```

I know using some other method like floor division would solve this exercise pretty easily. So getting the right answer is not really what I'm looking for. I was just wondering why I get an error and how to improve my code so that it works. Thanks.

Comment: "Timed Out" isn't a real error. Your code is just too slow to be accepted by that website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "timed out" error is not python-related. It comes from the website you are using. They seem to be setting a time limit, so that they force you to create an efficient solution. In  your case, obviously the website passes intentionally too large numbers for the values of `big` and `small`, and the double loop takes too long. So, they *want you* to use the other method that would solve the problem pretty easily.

Answer (score 0):

The answer by Blue Note is correct in that this is not a Python error but a limit imposed by the site. Your nested `for` Koop was taking too long.

You are right that floor division is the way to approach this. Python has a great function called `divmod()` that returns a tuple of the quotient and remainder of dividing one number by another. It can do this in one line.

I have given an example below. It assumes you only need the number of times `small` is needed once `big` is divided into `goal` a whole number of times.

```
def make_chocolate(small, big, goal):

    # Get remainder after dividing big into goal
    # divmod() returns a tuple of (quotient, remainder)
    # We just need the remainder at index 1
    remainder = divmod(goal, big)[1]

    # Need to divide this by small (default = 1)
    return remainder / small
```

I have kept the same function name; `make_chocolate()` :)